# Installing ssh-keyscan on Alpine linux?

Tags: github, docker, alpine-linux

In order to successfully clone a private repository into an Alpine-based docker, I needed to run the following command:
 `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

But since ssh-keyscan isn't part of Alpine linux (by default), I have to install it first with apk. The problem is: I dont know how - and I can't find it anywhere on Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command you're looking for is actually `ssh-keyscan` and you can easily find it using [pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents](http://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=ssh-keyscan&path=&name=&branch=&repo=&arch=).

Comment: Stackoverflow requires you to show the contents of the link, as links can often change over time.

Answer (score 44):

This took way too long to find out as its not documented anywhere:

```
apk update && apk add openssh
```

or alternatively:

```
apk add -qU openssh
```

Comment: The `openssh` dependency installs the sftp server and ssh server packages as well. `openssh-client` will install just the client which is all that's needed for `ssh-keyscan`.

Answer (score 23):

This would do the job:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client \
 && ssh-keyscan github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You can find the content of an Alpine linux package on this website:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=openssh-client&arch=x86&repo=main